# Is "on a spring midnight" correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

I think I have seen people use "on a summer night", but I don't know whether "on a spring midnight" is correct or not. I hope I can find the answer here

Comment: There have been several books with *[on] **a midnight clear*** in the title, but it's a quirky construction that wouldn't normally be used. Nor would we normally refer to *a winter midnight* the same as *a winter evening* or *a spring morning*. Perhaps because midnight is a *specific point* in time rather than a *period* of time, but we don't seem to be able to succinctly refer to ***midday / midnight on some unspecified day** [within a specified season]* in English.

Comment: "You could hear birds in her voice: ravens at a winter midnight, eagles high over the Alps, the wild geese calling us home."

Comment: "Fig. 15g represents histograms of δT ≥ 36 gammas depending on the latitude and local time. They have the characteristic probability of beiing observed at the close to noon and midnight hours with a trend to be larger **on** a summer midday and **at** a winter midnight." Bold emphasis mine; 1965 [US Senate report](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Committee_Prints/ijL-_yonpl8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22at+a+winter+midnight%22&pg=RA2-PA726&printsec=frontcover) about (I think) the Earth's magnetic field measured by satellites.

Comment: I think most native English speakers would usually phrase it **on a midnight in Spring**.

Comment: @PeterJennings Except I don't think we need the capital S - or do we?

Comment: @WS2 - these days, only if they are personified, e.g. Oh my love is Spring, when she dresses the trees in blossoms!  Otherwise they are common nouns except for specific things like Spring Break, which seems to be an American thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "on a summer night" but you can't say "on a spring midnight."

You can use **summer** as an adjective to describe night because both are extended periods of time (spring is late March to late June and night might be sunset to sunrise). **Midnight is different because it is a specific time** (12:00 am). You have to use "at" and the time:

> On a spring night **at midnight**...
>
> **At midnight** on a spring night...

Another example:

> On a **spring 3:00** (*incorrect* because 3:00 is a specific time)
>
> On a **spring afternoon** (*correct* because afternoon is an extended period)
>
> **At 3:00** on a spring afternoon (*correct*)

You can, however, use midnight as an adjective to describe a specific time:

> It's a midnight performance of the play.

This indicates that the performance begins at midnight (a specific time).

Comment: OP’s phrase was “on a spring midnight”, and you say that the preposition should instead be “at”. Are you suggesting that “at a spring midnight” would be acceptable?

Comment: No, you have to say "at midnight on a spring night" or "on a spring night at midnight."

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why? I think that that would greatly help this answer.

Comment: You can't say "on a spring midnight" because midnight is a specific, exact time, namely 12:00 am.  Spring, fall, day and night are not specific times. They represent ranges of time.  Similarly, you can't say "on a spring 3:00" but you can say "on a spring afternoon."

Comment: I revised my answer to hopefully make it more clear.